# Lebesgue Measure of the set of roots of a complex exponential equation

Tags: polynomials, power-series, roots, lebesgue-measure

In the following equation $\{\beta_i\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^N$  are non-zero complex numbers:
$\sum_{i=1}^N \beta_i e^{\alpha_i t} = 0$.
I would like to know if the Lebesgue measure of the set $\{t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ such that the above equation holds is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The set of zeros of a non-constant analytic function is discrete, therefore at most countable and of Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate or provide a resource where I can find a proof that the set is discrete? And by discrete, do you mean isolated?

Comment: 1) See e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipleofPermanence.html  
2) See e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteSet.html